# Gateway error: unable to read response or response is empty

Tags: checkout, payment-gateway, authorize.net

All of the sudden, this morning our website stopped taking orders. When anyone tries to check out, they get message

> Gateway error: unable to read response or response is empty

Have no idea what's happening. After searching The Mighty Internet, I found possible problem with server, which can be resolved with server or apache restart. The problem is that website is on shared hosting, so we can't do that.

Our gateway is `authorize.net` - tried calling them, they are saying they have nothing to do with it.

I checked the exception log, this is what I see:

```
    2017-03-03T03:48:00+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: Unable to read response, or response is empty' in /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(1298): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(510): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_postRequest(Object(Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet_Request))
#2 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '96.98', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#3 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(443): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '96.98')
#4 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(395): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#5 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(608): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#6 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(410): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#7 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(348): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#8 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(898): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#9 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1116): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#10 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#11 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#12 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#13 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#14 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#15 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(812): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#16 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(581): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#17 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#18 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#19 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Also, in system.log i see this:

> 2017-03-03T03:58:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::unsetChild()  in
>   /homepages/15/d474397241/htdocs/new-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
>   on line 474

Any ideas anybody on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what seemed to happen was the problem with server/hosting company - 1&1. This website was hosted on shared hosting and they couldn't/wouldn't reboot the server (I saw many topics on forums saying that it'd resolve the issue). So, I moved it to my own VPS, and the moment I moved it, all troubles were gone. Ta-da!

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact same error with Paypal Payflow. Rebooting the server resolved it for us. Likely a cached invalid DNS entry or SSL Cert.